# segmentation fault when trying to increase array size and insert value to it in c

Tags: arrays, c

i am trying to make an array of strings with 10 chars in each string, and amount of string is unknown , so each time i have a new string , i need to increase the array size by one and insert the string in the new index.
the program prints only one string and then segmentation fault.
why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void StoreStrings(char ***,int *);
int main()
{
    int i;
    char **strings = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int size=0;
 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    StoreStrings(&strings,&size);
    printf("%s\n",strings[size]);
    size++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void StoreStrings(char ***storage,int *size)
{
    
    char *string = NULL;
    char **temp= (char**)realloc(*storage,(*size+1) * sizeof(char*));
     string="000000000110";
     if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate more memory.\n");
        
    }
    else
    {
   
    *storage=temp;
    *storage[*size] = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
    
    strcpy(*storage[*size],string);
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location. So by debugging you should easily be able to spot your problem.

Comment: All `*storage[*size]` should be `(*storage)[*size]`, including the one in the `strcpy` call. [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) : it's what's for dinner. And passing `size` by address is pointless unless you're actually planning on modifying the target via dereference in the function (which you should) rather than back in `main` (which you shouldn't).